# Smart Switch for pool light

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I had a led pool light that switches colors when you press the light switch in the house on/off. On the back of the switch I only have a black, white, and ground wire with no load wire. Can I use a "smart switch" with this?

The system I'm using is a Wink hub.

[image: manuel]

[image: manuel 2]

Comment: Does it also switch the light on and off? How?

Comment: Yes it does. I'm not sure what you mean by the how?

Comment: Is it a normal light switch or a special switch for the LED? Is the pool light 120V or low voltage? Is the switch wired directly to the pool LED or is there a transformer or some type of controller in between? Is it a different color every time you turn it on, is it just the action of quickly turning on-off-on that changes color, or something else? Have any model #'s (of pool LED, and the switch if it's not a standard light switch)?

Comment: It is a normal switch. I believe it is wired to a transformer and then to the light. I'm not 100% on the low voltage or 120v? Is there an easy way to tell? It changes colors every time you turn it on and off quickly. Just normal on and off stays the same color. The pool light is a jandy pro series nichless led rgb.

Comment: So all you're asking for is a 120VAC SPST Wink-compatible switch? How does the house switch  changes the color **without** turning the  LED on and off?  You need three positions to  be able to do that.  Give us the model number of the existing switch & preferably a photo of the backside, showing the existing connections.

Comment: The switch has two positions and yes it turns the light on and off. I'm attaching a couple pages from the Manuel for the light.

Comment: VTC as off-topic - product recommendation

Comment: "black, white, and ground wire with no neutral", but look at what you posted, white is always neutral I see it clearly marked over and over again.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft He is using a "trick" LED designed to be controlled by a plain light switch, i.e. retrofit.  It treats momentary power disconnect as a command to change colors.  You also see fan-light combos capable of this kind of trick.  The electronics probably have a capacitor to carry them through a second or two of power loss.

Comment: Reworded question to be more general. I disagree with close vote; the question is more about "is this possible and how do I do it" vs "find me a product".

Comment: @Harper aha, thanks.  So what he really needs is a stuttering relay :-)

Comment: So it seems after doing more research that diagram does say there is a nuetral but it really isn't? I believe I have a switch loop which ultimately means that I can not put a smart switch there. I don't care about manually pushing the button to switch colors. I really just wanted a timer.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is a plain switch, a dumb 12VAC transformer for the pool lights (finally, someone who takes pool safety seriously, yay!) and several "smart" LED lights with a trick.  They can change colors if power is interrupted for a moment.  And they can all do this in sync, which is usually the hard part.

You are now implementing a "connected home" platform, and you'd like to control these LEDs.  You're looking for some sort of glue/middleware device that will let Wink address the LEDs and change their colors.  **Nope**.

### Not supported

You can put a smart-switch on their supply, sure.  You can have the Wink switch them on and off, sure.  Wink *might* even be able to turn them on and off quickly, as needed to switch their colors.  But Wink won't understand what it's doing or *why* it's doing it.

There won't be a way to tell Wink "make the pool orange" and have it tip-tap out the command to make those lights orange.  There may, but it would involve some special software coding; the question is whether Wink gives you the platform/language to do that.  Such a command series would not *remember* where the lamps are now, and certainly can't *see* them, so it would have to start the sequence from a cold reset-to-white, so it would take 10-15 seconds to reach any particular color.  On the other hand, Christmas light controllers do that kind of thing for breakfast, so maybe.

This is a hard problem, and it is *unsupported*: there's nobody to call for support to make this work, as you are discovering.

Though, given the cost of these things, it might be worth contacting the factory.  You can bet this has come up before.  They might even have a solution, or be motivated to develop one.  Their customer base are exactly the sort to do smart-home tech.

### Or start over

One could go with LED lights designed to work with Wink -- or alternately, a *controller* designed to work with Wink.  I don't think you care if they're individually addressible, so that's a plus.  The big minus would be if this forces you to 120V lights - because you are quite correct to keep 120V away from your pool.  Electricity is much more lethal in water, because you can't pull your hand away, and it only needs to stun you to drown you.

The good news is if you can get a Lutron dimmer that plays with Wink, maybe you can find an RGB controller that works with Wink too.  I have started to see them from name-brand companies, so hopefully.  Those controllers are designed for LED *strips*, input 12 volts *DC*, and output 3 channels (4 wires, R G B and common) which go direct to simple LEDs. That would require you to run 4-wire cable down to each of your pool light locations (I sure hope they're in conduit).  And thermostat cable would suffice since you're at 12V.

Answer (score 0):

You can just install any non-dimmer "smart switch" (compatible with your system) following the manufacturer's instructions. If it says it can control motors/appliances/lights, it should be fine to control your transformer load.

For nearly all smart switches, there must be a neutral wire available so be sure you have one in the switch box already.

One thing I will note to watch out for: since you require a quick on-off-on change to cycle the light color, make sure the smart switch and your controller is capable of doing it quickly enough (or you can build a macro/sequence to do that for you). I've noticed some of the 'smart' home stuff can be slow, especially when wifi is involved, so it takes a second after you press the button on your control to when the load is actually switched.

Answer (score -1):

a quick web search turned up this.

[lutron dimmer switch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LEWQY6C)

It says Wink compatible.

**Sorry i put a link to a dimmer but they have a regular switch in the same line of wink compatible devises**

The white wire is the neutral or common wire.

Comment: No it is not the neutral. I also do not think a dimmer switch will work. A dimmer will give continuous power to the led pool light and it won't turn off or switch colors

Comment: You know what, when I posted the pic I saw that. So I guess I do have a neutral then. I'm still not sure if a dimmer would work